While download magento2.4.6 using composer geeting below error
Hi every on while download the Magento 2.4.6 getting the velow error. i done every configuraion accroding to requirement still geeting below error.
[Composer\Downloader\TransportException]
The "https://repo.magento.com/packages.json" file could not be downloaded (HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found)
Please help on this. thank you in advanse.


Add an file composer.phar in root and execute below cmd.

composer.phar create-project --repository-url=https://repo.magento.com/magento/project-community-edition:2.4.6

Check if any blocking the Firewall

Remove the repo.magento.com from the repository section of the composer.json file and then try to install the repo  modules separately

Previous answer is right you need to specify the auth.json keys but you also need to specify it in the composer.json, which might be what you are missing there in the repositories section
   "magento": {
            "type": "composer",
            "url": "https://repo.magento.com/"
        },

